# Can't open more than max number of tabs with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to open a list of different URLs, opening one per tab, but when the number exceeds 20 ~ 21, stop opening tabs.

I've tried to separate the list into groups of 20, and creating new instances of the webdriver, and that works fine, but I would like to know if it's a way to enable more number of tabs using the same instance?

```python
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

for i in range(30):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")

print(len(driver.window_handles))
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

I was trying, to open 30 tabs at once but only opens 21.
I'm using python 3.5.0, Firefox 68.0.2 & geckodriver 0.24.0

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you want to open 30 tabs. Generally, you can close the tab once the operations on the tab is done.

Comment: Well, @supputuri, I try to watch over a number of websites and the tools than I already have, it's a script that uses i macros & kantu. So, I thought that using only one script and the Selenium could do it more... 'efficient?', than doing it almost manually. And, actually, I recently started using Selenium, so my first approach was to replicate what I already do with Kantu, and try to understand what happens...kind of. But I get your point. I know it would be more efficient if I open one tab at a time, do my stuff and move on to the other. I just don't want to keep wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the stackoverflow tab, you should see a yellow bar saying the rest has been blocked by the pop-up blocker. (This happens because `execute_script` runs the script in the context of the web page.)

To override, set [dom.popup_maximum](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.popup_maximum) preference to a larger value:

```
opts = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
opts.set_preference("dom.popup_maximum", 50)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
```

Comment: Thanks Nickolay, that solves it! dou you know a link where I can find more documentation about this 'preferences'? for Firefox, I was looking for it, but It's hard to find. I would appreciate.

Comment: There's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences but I'm not sure documentation on what exactly are you looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't make use of "window.open()" to get new tabs or windows opened. Instead use the new WebDriver [New Window](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#new-window) API, which all the latest versions of the official Selenium bindings have been already integrated. Note, it's not part of all the drivers yet, but for recent Firefox releases it works.

Given that you are using the Python bindings the following can be used:

```
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
```

By using this approach there shouldn't be a limitation for opening a lot of tabs.

Comment: AttributeError: 'SwitchTo' object has no attribute 'new_window'

Comment: Actually the new API was never released for the Selenium 3 Python bindings. You will have to use a Selenium 4 alpha release to actually make use of it.

Comment: @Henrik, i'm using latest chrome and chromedriver, selenium 4.0b4, switch_to.new_window fails with this error --> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Failed to open new tab - no browser is open"} (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)

Comment: As the error shows there is no open Chrome browser present. You should make sure that Selenium was able to create a browser instance through chromedriver first, before running any command that is requiring an active WebDriver Session.

For a better diagnosis a code example or [more detailed logs](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging) would be necessary.

Comment: @Henrik, i posted more info here, you're welcome to take a look, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970276/selenium-4-0-0b4-failed-to-open-new-tab-no-browser-is-open